# Querying a cte - The multi-part identifier could not be bound. How do I fix this so I can query the table? New to SQL accounting background

Tags: sql, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group, common-table-expression

I am trying to extract a dataset which joins 3 tables

- Employee E
- AbsenceTypes AT
- AbsenceBalance AB

In the data set I need the most recent record from `AB.BalanceTime` for each `AB.EmployeeUID` by `AB.AbsenceTypesUID`.

The data set is correct with the output I need, where it fails is when I query the CTE.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TOP (1000) 
        AB.[UID],
        AB.BalanceTime,
        AB.AbsenceTypesUID,
        AB.Mins,
        E.FullName,
        E.FirstName, E.LastName,
        AB.EmployeeUID,
        AT.LongName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AB.[UID], AB.EmployeeUID ORDER BY AB.BalanceTime DESC) AS RUN
    FROM 
        [RiteqDB].[dbo].[AbsenceBalance] AB
    LEFT JOIN 
        [RiteqDB].[dbo].Employee E ON AB.EmployeeUID = E.UID
    LEFT JOIN 
        [RiteqDB].[dbo].AbsenceTypes AT ON AB.AbsenceTypesUID = AT.UID
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE RUN = 1 AND E.FullName = 'john citizen'
```

Error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
> The multi-part identifier "E.FullName" could not be bound.

I have googled the problem & from what I understand the joined tables do not interact with the CTE which is why it fails with the condition below.

```
AND E.FullName = 'john citizen'
```

How can I alter the script so I can query the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table alias `E` is defined *inside* the CTE only, not in the outer query. In that scope, there is only one (derived) table, that is called `cte`, and that has all column names that the CTE returns.

In other words, you can just do:

```
with cte as (...)
select * 
from cte
where run = 1 and fullname = 'john citizen'
```

If you really want to use aliases, then alias the CTE, and then:

```
with cte as (...)
select c.* 
from cte c
where c.run = 1 and c.fullname = 'john citizen'
```